# Can't connect to Wireless on Debian Linux (using wpa_supplicant)

Tags: linux

I've been trying to connect my Debian Linux image to my wi-fi network at home. I have used "ssh" to login to my BeagleBone green Wireless device from a virtual Linux machine(this works fine with internet).

I have been following this guide:

https://www.linuxbabe.com/debian/connect-to-wi-fi-from-terminal-on-debian-wpa-supplicant

To the point where I type the:

```
sudo wpa_supplicant -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf -i wlan0
```

and I get the following error:

[image: The error I get]

It seems like the connection is established but disconnceted again in a loop - or how to read these errors?

I have checked and double-checked the contents of `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` and it appears to store my network and code as intented.

Hope anyone here have inputs or maybe some experience in how to handle or bypass this error!

Comment: Anything in `dmesg`? Missing firmware?

Comment: Please add textual output as text, enclosed in code brackets `{ }` on the edit box top bar to preserve formatting. The client associates successfully but immediately deassociates. Reason code 3 translates to disconnection because the client is leaving / has left the BSS or ESS, so something's funky with the Wi-Fi adapter. Arch Linux forums have a possible solution: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=216540